# unterminated string literal error in salesforce

Tags: salesforce

I am trying to get a value from salesforce class into a javascript variable. I am able to get the value if its a single line value, but if its multiline textarea it gives a unterminated string literal error

```
caseUpdate.Description = "{!ac__c.C_Info__c}";
```

After googling for sometime i came to know we can have  a workaround for this by having a hidden field and using DOM storing it using the document.getElement.Id. But i am calling this code on a button click so i would not be able to create a input text or hidden field value. 
Any body who can provide an way to do it?

Thanks
Prady

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because of line breaks. merge fields are rendered unescaped into the output stream meaning that CRLFs push into a new line and break javascript strings. Either use the div/input trick or use Apex to replace `\r\n`'s in the field with `<br/>` or whatever best suits the purpose. Also keep in mind that " will also terminate your JS string.

The easiest way is to just include a function in your extension and then you can use it across board

```
public String FixNewLine(String s) {
    if (s != null) return s.replaceAll('\r\n', '<br/>').replaceAll('"', '\\"');
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Its a standard sf page so cant use the div trick. document.getElementById('desc1").value="{!ac__c.C_Info__c}";
var desc= document.getElementById('desc1").value.replace(/[\r\n]+/g, " ");
alert(desc); This also gives the same error

Comment: No, the div trick is to render a value inside a div element, then retrieve it using innerHTML

Answer (score 1):

You should just be able to use the standard Salesforce JSENCODE() function if you are using OnClick Javascript in a button. This will escape any characters for you.

See [the documentation](https://cs8.salesforce.com/help/doc/user_ed.jsp?section=Customizing&target=customize_functions.htm#JSENCODE&loc=help).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue but was able to fix it!  The trick is the JSENCODE function.  Its basically {!JSENCODE(Obj.Field)}";   So you are replacing your merge field with this function and nesting the merge field itself within the function.  In my scenario I ended up with opptyObj.Description="{!JSENCODE(Case.Description)}"; as my total syntax.  First calling upon my set object and field, and then the merge data to populate it.