# unterminated string literal error in salesforce due to data in multiple lines

Tags: javascript, salesforce

I am using a standard page on which there is a button in which JavaScript code is written. It is calling a Controller (Class).

When I ever used click on the button,It gives me error:

```
A problem with the OnClick JavaScript for this button or link was encountered:
unterminated string literal.
```

Javascript:

```
try
{
  alert('hi1');
}
catch(Err)
{
  alert('Error  in creation'+Err);
}
```

After searching and done some hit and trial,used a simple alert code above.

I found that. whenever i used data where there is a new line space between them i.e. data in multiple times.This error encounters no matter if you are using that particular field in JavaScript code and class or not.

I found similar problem here: [unterminated string literal error in salesforce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5794593/unterminated-string-literal-error-in-salesforce)
but solution is not specified in above link.

Comment: Have you tried replacing the newline characters with something else?

Comment: Hi Lee,thanks for reply.What i am trying to say is : i am not using that field anywhere in the JavaScript code. I am just simply using alert('hi');.

Nothing else you can also try just create a custom button on sfdc detail page ,call JavaScript on it and put data in any Long text area field with multiple line.You will get same error. Any work around for this?

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping SUBSTITUTE() or even URLENCODE() around the value of your long text field, then decode from JS?

Back in S-Control days I've been cheating by putting the long text values in `<p id="myId" style="visibility:hidden">{!mergefield}</p>` and then referencing them with getElementById...

If you're really calling your controller from JS then probably either you have control over newlines (replace them with something?) or you don't need to display whole error msg. Maybe err.details? Also - would help to use proper JS debugging tool...